# Orientdb OrientGraph OServerCommandAbstract

Tags: graph, orientdb

What is the recommended approach for getting an instance of an OrientGraph from a custom command (OServerCommandAbstract subclass)?  I've seen the OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract but that appears to be designed for the document api.

I believe the OrientGraphFactory is the preferred approach to getting OrientGraph instances.  Just trying to figure out what the best practice approach is.  Should I create a singleton factory and create instances from there?

Thanks.

Comment: OrientGraphFactory is the suggested one.

Comment: Thanks @Lvca.  I'll go with that approach.